# Internationalization of alert messages in javascript for play2.0 framework

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

Kindly suggest me some ways to implement internationalization in alert messages of javascript using play framework.
I tried as mentioned in below link :
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.1/tags#i18n
I am getting error on this line #{i18n /}.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The docs you linked to is for Play 1.x which is entirely different from Play 2. The relevant docs for play 2.0 can be found here: 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/JavaI18N for Java, or http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaI18N for Scala

Also, note that the I18N support in Play is a serverside solution, so if you want client side localization this is not something the Play localization API:s does for you.

Comment: I have tried to implement above scenario using jsMessages plugin but i am facing 1 issue.kindly look into this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192554/play-framework-2-0-issue-in-rendering-view).